# How to make flask app with projects written in two different Python versions work in endpoints?

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose

I’m building a flask api in which I have to use two different Python projects written in 2 different versions. One is a Python project built on version 3.8+, and another is a proprietary package compatible for version <3.7. I get errors if I use a single version and try to run it, and fixing errors would be too much and potentially break the system behavior. The flask api runs on docker. What are my options to make both Python projects work on the single flask app?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to use two different Python projects written in 2 different versions"?
Do you mean that you have 2 dependencies, that are not compatible?

Comment: Yes. I have two different endpoints which depends on these projects.

Answer (score -2):

If you have multiple dependencies that are incompatible (e.g. one requires Python >= 3.8, one < 3.8), then you can't use them in the same Flask server.
Flask runs with Python, and therefore you need to select one Python version with one set of compatible dependencies.

Some potential solutions to your project:

- Choose some alternative packages that is compatible with your Python version.
- If you have access to one of those dependencies (e.g. by modifying the original project directly, or fork them if it's an open source project), try to make them compatible with the Python version that you have.
- Run 2 Flask servers instead of just one. E.g. one with Python 3.7, that implements the endpoint which requires the old dependency, and one Python 3.8 Flask server, that implements the other endpoint and just redirects the 3.7 requests to the other server. Alternative you could also use something like Nginx to split the requests between the servers.